# Provide additional behavior when editing a cell in JTable

Tags: java, jtable, tablecelleditor

I am creating a app in Java. I need to provide additional behavior when editing of a cell in a JTable. So ideally this will happen when the cell loses focus after editing. Depending upon some post processing I might reset the value of the cell. I tried using a a Cell Editor but it is not giving me the desired behavior.

In the default JTable only when I Double click a cell it becomes editable. But in my implementation of CellEditor the cell becomes editable as soon as it comes into focus.

Here is the code for the My custom CellEditor,

```
public class ParameterDefinitionEditor 
    extends AbstractCellEditor
    implements TableCellEditor{

    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel;

public ParameterDefinitionEditor(DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel,
JTable table) { 

        super();
        this.table = table;
        this.defaultTableModel = defaultTableModel;

        TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
        columnModel.getColumn(0).setCellEditor(this);

}

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, 
                            Object value, 
                         boolean isSelected, 
                        int row, 
                         int column) {

        if (isSelected) {
            // Do some processing.
        } 

        ((JTextField)component).setText((String)value);

        // Return the configured component
        return component;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {

        return ((JTextField)component).getText();
    }


}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: for the record: this is an invalid implementation of CellEditor - it _must_ notify its listener when editing is terminated for internal reasons!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Depending upon some post processing I
>   might reset the value of the cell.

You can do this right in the cell editor if you desire by overriding the stopCellEditing() method.

> In the default JTable only when I
>   Double click a cell it becomes
>   editable. But in my implementation of
>   CellEditor the cell becomes editable
>   as soon as it comes into focus.

Extend the DefaultCellEditor. This is controlled by the setClickCountToStart() method.

> So ideally this will happen when the
>   cell loses focus after editing

I agree with the other suggestion that you should probably be adding the TableModelListener to the TableModel. Although depending on your requirement you may want to consider using the [Table Cell Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/).

Comment: I actually like the TableCellListener example that you have put up at the link. But my environment is Java 1.5 so in effect I cannot use the utility since "convertRowIndexToModel" is not available in 1.5. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Also while we are at it, Is there a way to disable this behavior for certain columns?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think by providing custom cell editor serves your purpose.

If you want to do some processing based on user actions then your table model should have
a set of listeners (that implement TableModelListener) and your logic should be put
in the "tableChanged" method.

Check this section on Swing tutorial as well:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 1):

i achieved that type of behaviour by overriding stopCellEditing ( i use a custom implementation of AbstractCellEditor )

```
public boolean stopCellEditing()
{
String s = (String) getCellEditorValue();
if ( ! valueValidator.isValid(s) )
  {
  editorComponent.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));        
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
  return false;
  }
}
else { ........
```