# How to add row MyTableModel created AbstractTableModel from JavaDerby

Tags: java, swing, jtable, derby, abstracttablemodel

I have datas in JavaDerby database.I can not add row my table model which is created by AbstractTableModel.What is wrong.

MyTableModel class

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

private Vector str;
.....other codes......
public void AddingRow(Object[] row){
    str.add(row);
    fireTableRowsInserted(str.size() - 1, str.size() - 1);
}
}
```

My Result class

```
public class Results {
  public static void myresult(){
    Object[] row=new Object[11];
    rs=stm.executeQuery(sqlResult); // I can connect to database        
    MyTableModel model=new MyTableModel();
    while (rs.next()){
         for (int v=1;v<12;v++)
         {
          row[v-1]=rs.getObject(v); 
          }
         model.AddingRow(row);
    }
    rs.close(); 
}
}
```

Where I make mistakes. Thank for your help.

Comment: Compare to this complete working [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12352838/230513).

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them