# Set JTable Cell Disable or Enable based on condition?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, tablecelleditor

I have a `JTable`. It has four columns; the last column is checkbox column. I want to make the checkbox enable or disable, based on condition.

Consider that the last column value (check box value) is true, then user is not allowed to unselect the checkbox. if value is false, then user is allowed to select the checkbox.

Is there any way? I have tried table `iscellEditable()`, `setRowSelectionAllowed()`. But, these methods are not fulfill my concept.

Comment: please show us your code, it will be easier to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7920159/230513), the code below conditions the `isCellEditable()` implementation based on the model's state for that row. Once checked, a row cannot be unchecked. You can alter the appearance of such rows as desired using a suitable [*renderer*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12352838/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082475/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920068
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526779
 */
public class CheckOnce extends JPanel {

    private static final int CHECK_COL = 1;
    private static final Object[][] DATA = {
        {"One", Boolean.FALSE}, {"Two", Boolean.FALSE},
        {"Three", Boolean.FALSE}, {"Four", Boolean.FALSE},
        {"Five", Boolean.FALSE}, {"Six", Boolean.FALSE},
        {"Seven", Boolean.FALSE}, {"Eight", Boolean.FALSE},
        {"Nine", Boolean.FALSE}, {"Ten", Boolean.FALSE}};
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {"Number", "CheckBox"};
    private DataModel dataModel = new DataModel(DATA, COLUMNS);
    private JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);

    public CheckOnce() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(
             new Dimension(250, 10 * table.getRowHeight()));
    }

    private class DataModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        public DataModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames) {
            super(data, columnNames);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
            super.setValueAt(aValue, row, col);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            if (col == CHECK_COL) {
                return getValueAt(0, CHECK_COL).getClass();
            }
            return super.getColumnClass(col);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            Object o = getValueAt(row, col);
            boolean b = o instanceof Boolean && (Boolean) o;
            return col == CHECK_COL && !b;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckOne");
        frame.add(new CheckOnce());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i customized this code for my convenient. now its working fine.