# Access JTable cell component

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Ok I have a JTable where I'm displaying a JList on every cell.  To do this I had to implement TableCellRenderer and extend DefaultCellEditor.  Here is where I return the actual JList to be rendered in GUI.

What I want to do is when user de-selects an item from a JList, I want to also de-select all items for all JLists for that table row starting at the clicked column.

My problem is that I can't figure out a way to de-select all items that come after the current clicked table column. All I can access is this DefaultListModel.  I guess I need to access the actual JList in order to remove all selected items.

Below is method I'm using.  Any ideas how to do this? Thanks.

```
public void deselectFromLocation(int row_, int column_){
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table1.getModel();

        int cols = dtm.getColumnCount();
        for(int i=column_; i<cols;i++){
            PCSListModel lm = (PCSListModel) dtm.getValueAt(row_, i);
            //How can I access the actual JList object in order to  remove all selected items? 
            //The PCSListMode is DefaultListModel and has no access to JList object. Thanks.


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, your renderer and editor obtain the existing selection state from your `TableModel`, perhaps updating an instance of `ListSelectionModel` that is used as part of preparing the component for use. You can update the *other* model value(s) in your implementation of `stopCellEditing()`. Your `TableModel` will have to  fire a suitable `TableModelEvent` for the other cells; do *not* do so for the value being edited. A related example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12352838/230513).

Comment: I was firing the wrong event when deselecting other list models from my posted method.  You were right, it works from stopCellEditing(). I just added this line in my above method and it worked dtm.fireTableCellUpdated(row_,i);  Thanks for leading me to the right direction.