# change color of an jtable cell that was edited more than once

Tags: java, swing, jtable, background-color, tablecellrenderer

I've been looking for this answer for some time, and could not find it. I already have a class that extends a DefaultTableCellRenderer, but there are certain columns that need to have different background color, only when it's edited twice. It tooks me tons of time.

Comment: Have a flag associated with the value (either directly or indirectly) which can be changed when the `setValueAt` is called (and actually changes the value) so that the cell renderer can extract it - this could be associated with the row/cell object or maintained by the `TableModel` itself

Comment: Following @MadProgrammer's suggestion, start with this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12352838/230513) and change `Row#state` to `Row#editCount`.